# Please suggest the bestter solution to parse a string in multiple python dictionary

Tags: python, json, regex, parsing

String is:

```
str = '{"Speed":0,"Tracktime":"2017-02-22 10:14:19.0","Latitude":12.9055766,"gpsstatus":1,"Longitude":77.4990283}{"Speed":1,"Tracktime":"2017-02-23 13:14:19.0","Latitude":12.9355766,"gpsstatus":0,"Longitude":77.5990283}'
```

My solution:

```
str.replace("}{","}|{").split("|")
```

is it the best way or it can be done in more optimised way?

Comment: Please show us what you tried so far so that we can help you find your errors.

Comment: @feedMe updated my question with my best solution

Answer (score 1):

Try with this-

```
import json
x='{"Speed":0,"Tracktime":"2017-02-22 10:14:19.0","Latitude":12.9055766,"gpsstatus":1,"Longitude":77.4990283}{"Speed":1,"Tracktime":"2017-02-23 13:14:19.0","Latitude":12.9355766,"gpsstatus":0,"Longitude":77.5990283}'
str1=x.split("}{")[0]
str2=x.split("}{")[1]
js1=json.loads(str1+"}")
js2=json.loads("{"+str2)
```

this is not a great solution,but it '' work for this kind of strings,you can use for loop to create more than 2 obj`s i'll update it once i come up with something good

Comment: str.replace("}{","}|{").split("|") is much better solution.